# Issue in Pybossa webhooks, how to execute it

Tags: python, flask, redis, webhooks, pybossa

I am working with the Pybossa webhooks, and found [this](https://github.com/Scifabric/webhooks) plugin to analyse the Pybossa results in real-time. I forked it but not getting how it is to be executed.

Currently, I am executing it as follows:

python app.py test_project

where test_project is my project_short_name. But, it is reverting me to index.html page of this repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873109/access-pybossa-database-trough-terminal/41351184#41351184

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a duplicate. This is regarding processing task runs in realtime, the other is regarding general pybossa maintenance via the command-line. This is a workflow automation question, the other is an interface question.

Comment: @JosephCoco Yes. That is exactly what I am am looking for by this question. I am able to execute and maintain Enki through command line but how to process task runs in real-time is what I require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it ! Look into `pybossa.model.event_listeners` you will find `push_webhook`function, it push webhook into queue. And it's called by `on_taskrun_submit, on_auditrun_submit` function in the same file.

If you really want to execute webhook manually, look into `pybossa.jobs`, you will find `webhook` function, it's where the webhook execute. You can call it manually like this:

```
def trigger_webhook(short_name, task_id=0, result_id=0):
    from pybossa.jobs import webhook
    from datetime import datetime
    from pybossa.core import project_repo

    with app.app_context():
        project = project_repo.get_by_shortname(short_name)

        payload = dict(event="task_completed",
                       project_short_name=project.short_name,
                       project_id=project.id,
                       task_id=task_id,
                       result_id=result_id,
                       fired_at=datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        webhook(project.webhook, payload)
```

I put this function in cli.py so I can call it handily.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't set it up myself, but it would seem you run both the [primary Pybossa site](http://docs.pybossa.com/en/latest/installing_pybossa.html) in addition to a custom microservice you can fork from the [webhooks project](https://github.com/Scifabric/webhooks).

1. Install and run the primary Pybossa server and create an admin account.
2. Install and run webhooks fork
3. Grab your API key from an admin's [account page](http://127.0.0.1:5000/account/admin/) on your primary PyBossa server.
4. In webhooks, Clone the settings.py.tmpl and update the information such as API key.
5. Run the microservice.
6. In Pybossa, Configure your project to use the webhook URL in your settings.
7. In webhooks, load the index.html page.

You would change the charts on the index page to display the results you're interested in. But like I said, this is just what I understand needs to be done. I haven't done it myself as I'm just going to modify the presenter JS to use the API to perform some operations I desire dependent on value of submitted answer. Best of luck.

Comment: As Joseph has said, that's the way to go :-) I'm the developer of PYBOSSA and the webhooks solution. The webhooks microservice needs to be run in parallel with your PYBOSSA server. This will make possible to analyze results in real time, as well as publish them.

Comment: @DanielLombrañaGonzález Can you please add more documentation with example related to the Webhooks part. I want to use Enki as webhook. I am stuck at index.html page with no results to return.

Comment: @joseph-coco I have a doubt. For the GET request to run on webhooks, there should be some trigger from the Pybossa server. Do I need to add the GET request code anywhere in my Pybossa code? Or, in other way, how exactly it is handled?

Comment: @DakshAgarwal Can you clarify what you mean by GET request to run on webhooks? You mean for a user just to see the index.html page of the webhook? Or do you mean for PYBOSSA to transfer project/task/task_run info to the webhook? I don't believe you should need to write additional code to tie webhooks and PYBOSSA together. But if you're trying to serve webhooks through PYBOSSA, I'm not sure how that's done either. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: @JosephCoco By GET request, I meant how Pybossa will transfer project/task/task_run information to the webhook, so that it is available to Enki in real time. I tried executing without any additional code but I don't see any request received on the webhooks part.

Comment: I haven't actually set up webhooks, since it didn't meet my use case. I would recommend emailing scifabric/PYBOSSA support, you'll probably get a response from @DanielLombrañaGonzález within 24 hours.

Comment: @JosephCoco I figured out on thing that posts the message thru webhooks. 'python app_context_rqworker.py scheduled_jobs super high medium low email maintenance' helps in triggering the webhooks. But, running this simultaneously can't run with Pybossa. So, again webhooks is not running in real-time. Anyway I mailed the author. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The problem is that you are probably using the same redis prefix for PYBOSSA and Webhooks server. The settings file for webhooks has an option for specifying whatever you wan: https://github.com/Scifabric/webhooks/blob/master/settings.py.template#L8